# packager for iphone XML

Tags: iphone, xml, flash

I am trying to build my iphone app from a swf in windows using pfi but i run into this error:

```
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(117): error 105: application.icon.image29x29 contains an invalid value
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(117): error 105: application.icon.image29x29 contains an invalid value
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(118): error 105: application.icon.image57x57 contains an invalid value
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(118): error 105: application.icon.image57x57 contains an invalid value
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(119): error 105: application.icon.image72x72 contains an invalid value
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(119): error 105: application.icon.image72x72 contains an invalid value
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(120): error 105: application.icon.image512x512 contains an invalid value
C:\Users\tkazak\Adobe Flash Builder 4\iphoneTest\bin-debug\iphoneTest-app.xml(120): error 105: application.icon.image512x512 contains an invalid value
```

My xml looks like this:

```
 <icon>
        <image29x29>icons\icon29.png</image29x29> 
        <image57x57>icons\icon57.png</image57x57> 
        <image72x72>icons\icon72.png</image72x72> 
        <image512x512>icons\icon512.png</image512x512> 

 </icon>
```

Does the packager regard my xml values as invalid because of the backslashes?

Comment: Maybe. Try with the regular-style-backslashes?

Comment: Interesting... using flash. Probably this way will start getting some popularity now AppStore rules are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the forward slashes are fine. The issue was in my cmd line arguments. I used the refresher example where only a file name is specified for the icon http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/packager-for-iphone-refresher.html

So all I needed to do was change the last pfi argument to "icons" for the icons folder.